# Using c++ function pointer as signal handler.

Tags: c++, c

I'd like to add new handler to signal SIGUSR1 in my code. here's `signal` signature form header file `signal.h` :

`void   (*signal(int, void (*)(int)))(int);`

My handler is a member function, so I'm using `std::bind` to make the function fit in `signal` accepted input.

```
myclass::my_handler(int x);
```

Here's my conversion of the member function to `signal` accepted input:

```
std::bind(&myclass::my_handler, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

However, `std::bind` return the c++ representation of function pointer (a.k.a `std::function<void(int)>`) and I need the C representation which is `(void)(*)(int)`.

Should I do the casting forcefully, or perhaps there's c++ alternative for `signal` ?

Thanks

Comment: "*Should I do the casting forcefully*" - probably not "*or perhaps there's c++ alternative for signal*"  -- no. Don't use `signal()` at all, use `sigaction()` (but that doesn't solve your problem, you should probably just add some C glue code. Having a member function as a signal handler doesn't make too much sense if you think about the fact a signal is delivered *to your process*)

Comment: Force fully casting might not yield correct results. The ABI for C and C++ could be different.

Comment: Also, there's not much you can do safely in a signal handler anyways. The best thing to do is to just modify some `volatile sig_atomic_t` flag. (potentially after storing some other info like the signal number) Any actual processing should be done outside the signal handler.

Comment: @felixpalmen, Hi and thanks for your reply. I need the function as member of a class since this class contain other data that affect the handler behavior...

Comment: @Zohar81 your handler shouldn't have much behavior. Read [signal safety](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) for a list of functions you **can** call in a signal handler. Everything else would be dangerous.

Comment: @felixPalmen after I simplified my code, all I need from the signal handler is to wait until the signal `SIGUSR1` arrives (just like pthread_cond_t but also for other processes). do you suggest other way to do so ?

Comment: @Zohar81 see my comment above: have the signal handler raise a `volatile sig_atomic_t` flag and periodically check this from your main code. If you need to *wait* for a signal, you can use a "*self-pipe*" instead and block on it with `poll()`, `select()` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no portable way to convert a C++ function to a C function because they can have different ABIs.

What you can do is this declare a global variable cpphandler as -

```
std::function<void(int)> cpphandler = NULL;
```

Also declare a function as -

```
extern "C" {
    void signal_handler(int i);
}
void signal_handler(int i){
    cpphandler(i);
    return;
}
```

Now in the function where you want to create the binding do -

```
cpphandler = std::bind(&myclass::my_handler, this, std::placeholders::_1); 
signal(x, signal_handler); //replace x with whatever signal you want to install
```

This makes sure that the function `signal_handler` is created with C ABI. And calls the C++ function code with C++ ABI.

Now you can use the `signal` function with `signal_handler`.

Comment: "There is no portable way to convert a C++ function to a C function because they can have different ABIs.", partially correct statement but for the wrong reason. The reason that one generally cannot convert C++ to C functions is that C++ functions can have a context. If a context doesn't exist, then casting C++ functions to C function pointers is fine. For example, a lambda can be cast to a C function as long as it doesn't have a capture list.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist are you sure the context is the only reason? The C and C++ ABI could have different alignment requirements (for the stack pointer or the code), or the calling convention could be different.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. You can try to cast a lambda to a C function pointer and see that it works. That's a [counterexample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexample), right? ABI has nothing to do with it as long as you're compiling everything in one program. ABI comes to question when dealing with plugins, for example. That's another story.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I am afraid that is not a counter example. It is like saying since `x - 5 == 0` is true for `x = 5` implies that it is true for all x. I am not saying it __won't__ work (casting lambda to C function). Ofcourse it works on my machine, on your machine, on OPs machine. Doesn't mean it will work every where.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist also, no! ABI doesn't come to question only when plugins are used. A single compiler with a single translation unit can use different ABIs depending on what code it is dealing with. (That is essentially the reason behind the `extern "C"` ).

Comment: Your statement is: "C++ functions can never be converted to C functions". A single example suffices to disprove this statement, which I provided. Also the reason behind `extern "C"` is to create C linkage and disable name mangling. Sure, that has something to do with ABI. However, talking about C++ ABI has nothing whatsoever to do with the OP's question. Again, that's a whole other story. There's ABSOLUTELY no benefit in mentioning ABI here. The context is all that matters. I'm sorry but I can't ping-pong with you any longer. Please shutdown the discussion as it's branching. Have a nice day!

Comment: Have a nice day :)

Comment: @ajaybrahmakshatriya, the only problem with your proposal is that I need to set cpphandler from within one of the class methods, so your probably meant it would be a class member (because if it's a global variable, we're missing the all point of making the code looks neat)  ... but how can I call non static member from within a the c function ?? thanks

Comment: How are you going to get the object whose function must be called? Is it a global?

Comment: I wanted to call the handler from within one of the methods in my class. so I have the object pointer as `this`

Comment: `cpphandler = std::bind(&myclass::my_handler, this, std::placeholders::_1);` call this line in my answer with the appropriate context (where this is visible). This will create a binding with proper value of `this`. And the member of that object will be called. you might want to make cpphandler global and set its value from one of the functions of the object, so that `this` will be properly set.

Comment: does `cpphandler` is called from within the class method ? does `cpphandler` is class member or just local variable defined in stack ? maybe you can modify your code to exemplify your point ? It'd be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Zohar81 check the latest edit. Also with this method you can have just a single handler. If you need to have more handlers you will have to create more wrapper functions. But you cant create wrappers on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a C++ compiler, I suggest that you simply define a normal function that calls your member function handler:

```
void signal_handler_wrapper(int x)
{
   myclass::my_handler(x);
}
```

Then in your main code:

```
signal(SIGINT, signal_handler_wrapper);
```